# QGIS 3 installation fails due to wrong python found

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, homebrew

I try to install QGIS as seen in https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/issues/64 by executing:

```
brew install --no-sandbox qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev
```

but fail with:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
```

How can I fix this, as

```
python --version
Python 2.7.14

geoheil@eduroam-078-104-029-050 ~                                                                                           [17:34:02]
> $ python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

already returns the right versions of python?

## full error

```
brew install --no-sandbox qgis/qgisdev/qgis3-dev
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
No changes to formulae.

==> Installing qgis3-dev from qgis/qgisdev
==> Cloning https://github.com/qgis/QGIS.git
Updating /Users/geoheil/Library/Caches/Homebrew/qgis3-dev--git
==> Checking out branch master
==> /usr/local/bin/pip3 install --user future psycopg2 python-dateutil httplib2 pytz six nose2 pygments jinja2 pyyaml requests owslib
==> cmake -G Ninja -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/qgis3-d
Last 15 lines from /Users/geoheil/Library/Logs/Homebrew/qgis3-dev/02.cmake:
--   skipping QCA OpenSSL plugin C++ check
-- Found Libtasn1: /usr/local/include
-- Pedantic compiler settings enabled
-- Debug output enabled
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "1.4", but required
  is at least "3" (found /usr/local/bin/python3)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.11.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:155 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:696 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/qgis3-dev-20180411-72396-1w7hugc/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/issues

These open issues may also help:
Update qgis3-dev.rb https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/pull/63
Update qgis3-dev.rb https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/pull/61
Python 3.6.0 upgrade breaks existing qgis3-dev https://github.com/qgis/homebrew-qgisdev/issues/11

Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.
```